# laravel routes not work when is copied

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Hi I copy the routes 5 to 8 from 1 to 4 but change almost everything include the route name and args, but when I call I try to use the new edit the old one works.
what's wrong ? its in my routes?

if I deleted the old one works, but right now that's not a option, I have to keep both.

```
/*edit old*/
    Route::get('programacao/{localizacao}/{anoatual}/{cliente}/{programacao}/{item}/edit', array('as' => 'programacao.edit', 'uses' => 'ProgramacaoController@edit'));
    Route::post('programacao/atualizar', array('as' => 'programacao.update','uses' => 'ProgramacaoController@update'));

    Route::get('programacao/{localizacao}/{anoatual}/{cliente}/{programacao}', array('as' => 'programacao.show', 'uses' => 'ProgramacaoController@show'));
    Route::post('programacao/atualizarinfo', array('as' => 'programacao.updateinfo','uses' => 'ProgramacaoController@updateinfo'));



/*edit new*/
    Route::get('programacao/{go}/{localizacao}/{cliente}/{ano}/{item}/edicao', array('as' => 'programacao.edicao', 'uses' => 'ProgramacaoController@edicao'));
    Route::post('programacao/atualizacao', array('as' => 'programacao.atualizacao','uses' => 'ProgramacaoController@atualizacao'));

    Route::get('programacao/{go}/{localizacao}/{cliente}/{ano}', array('as' => 'programacao.mostrar', 'uses' => 'ProgramacaoController@mostrar'));
    Route::post('programacao/atualizarinformacao', array('as' => 'programacao.updateinformacao','uses' => 'ProgramacaoController@updateinformacao'));
```

thx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for Laravel...

```
programacao/{go}/{localizacao}/{cliente}/{ano}
```

and

```
programacao/{localizacao}/{anoatual}/{cliente}/{programacao}
```

Is the same URL

```
programacao/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}/{param4}
```

### How can you change that?

The simplest way is to just change the non-dynamic part (the part that isn't a paramater) for the different routes.

Here's an example:

```
Route::get('programacao-new/{go}/{localizacao}/{cliente}/{ano}', ...)
Route::get('programacao/{localizacao}/{anoatual}/{cliente}/{programacao}', ...)
```

(Obviously you would chose something more descriptive that just `-new`)

Alternatively you can use regular expressions to restrict route parameters.

I assume `ano` is a year so let's filter for only numbers:

```
Route::get('programacao/{go}/{localizacao}/{cliente}/{ano}', array(
    'as' => 'programacao.mostrar',
    'uses' => 'ProgramacaoController@mostrar'
))->where('ano', '[0-9]+');
```

As you can see, I added a [`where()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters) and the regular expression for numbers only.

That means if you enter the URL `programacao/foo/bar/test/2015` it will use the `programacao.mostrar` route. If the 4th parameter contains something else than a number, `programacao.updateinfo` will be used.

**Note** that the *more restricted* route (in this case `programacao.mostrar`) needs to be declared *before* the other route. Because Laravel goes through the routes in the order they get registered.

Comment: Thx man, now I got, i changed the new one just to prog and works fine! but I'v another question, if i'v the same name but with less params, will happen the same problem ? thx!

Comment: You're welcome. You can't have multiple routes with the same route name.